# "Name" of lower bound of inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The inclusion-exclusion principle when stopping after an even number of summands gives a lower bound on the cardinality of the union. I know that this result has a name but I cannot find it. Can you help me with it and providing me a name or a paper reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In probability, these inequalities are sometimes called the Bonferroni inequalities, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities) for instance.